# Finding time data in a .gpx file

Tags: qgis, gps, timestamp

This seems like a simple problem but I have searched for answers and apparently reached the limit of my experience.

I have a .gpx file and I am trying to see the time data for various points along the path. I have it open in QGIS right now with various track points visible and I want to know the time that the vessel was at each point.

I have run this through various .gpx viewers with no luck on finding that data.
I have opened the .gpx in various text editors and found that some time data is there but it is quite limited in number compared to the number of track points visible. I am suspecting that the time stamps I can see in the text files or when I open the file in excel are of the handful of waypoints in the file.

Having access to the timestamp of a track point seems like a basic function of gps data. I don't know if this file doesn't have it for some reason or if it's just that I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Hi AbeFroman, welcome to GIS SE. Can you share at least a sample of the data? Otherwise, I don't know how we could help. I guess after loading the gpx file to QGIS you opened the attribute table? If you don't see any timestamps there, then probably they don't exist (corrupted file?).

Comment: .gpx is XML you should be able to open it in the most editors - e.g. Notepad on Windows OS. If you dont find a <time></time> tag than it's not exported from the tracking device (my GARMIN GPSMAP has an option to export with or without timestamps).

Comment: If you have a timestamp in most cases it is ZULU time (Z).

Comment: The file is for a client, so I don't think I can upload it. I did select track points from the layers menu and open the attribute table. That produces a table with 27 columns and 11,337 rows. With "Null" in every value except for the point id cells. I can select waypoints from the layers menu and it pulls the time and date data in the attribute table for those. So I guess there just isn't data for the track points for some reasons? Side question, the timestamps for the waypoints, would those be from when the waypoint was created? The vessel got close to them but did not travel over them.

Answer (score 0):

Open the trackpoint layer

[image]

If the times have been recorded then you can find them from the trackpoints.

GPX is a hierarchical data format that does not transfer perfectly into GIS data model. In GIS the data layers are features which have a geometry and a set of attributes. Therefore a track is a line and if it had a timestamp then it would be the same for the whole track. IN GPX the track is made up from trackpoints which have their own attributes like time.
QGIS is placing the track points into the track_points layer and there you can find the times. If you want the see the track as a line and for example measure the length, open the tracks layer.

Further reading:
https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpx.html

There are specialized GPX viewers which make it easier to access and visualize the GPX data.